# pandas drop rows based on cell content and no headers

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a csv file with pandas that has no headers.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0)
```

csv file containing 1 row with several users:

```
admin
user
system
sysadmin
adm
administrator
```

I need to read the file to a df or a list except for example: `sysadmin`
and save the result to the csv file

```
admin
user
system
adm
administrator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select first columns, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and write to file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0) 

df[df.iloc[:, 0].ne('sysadmin')].to_csv(file, index=False)

#if there is csv header converted to column name
#df[df['colname'].ne('sysadmin')].to_csv(file, index=False)
```

If no header in csv need parameters like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None) 
df[df.iloc[:, 0].ne('sysadmin')].to_csv(file, index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try:---

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv') 
df=df.transpose()

df.columns=['admin','user','system','sysadmin','adm','administrator']
df.head()
```

I think this will work it out.
if not then try it:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('file.csv') 


df.columns=['admin','user','system','sysadmin','adm','administrator']
df.head()
```